# Django rest framework: custom pagination next/previous links

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, pagination

In the backend as the `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS` I am using the built-in `PageNumberPagination`.
Due to the reason that I use `vue.js` with `fetch`, I don't need to pass the whole url like provided by `django-rest-framework`:

```
"count": 5,
"next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/something/?page=2",
"previous": null
```

but only the part after the base url, e.g.:

```
/api/something/?page=2
```

or just the page number, so I could build my own endpoint e.g.:

```
if (!pageNumber) {
  let endpoint = "/api/something/"
} else {
  let endpoint = "/api/something/" + "?page=" + pageNumber;
}
```

What is the right way to do pagination with `django` and a JavaScript framework like `vue` using [bootstraps pagination component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/pagination/)?

Comment: What was your solution to this?

Comment: You need current_page and total_pages. Then in your front end your current page is `current_page`, back button is `current_page-1`, next button `current_page+1` and the amount of page items are `total_pages`

Answer (score 2):

Overwrite your pagination response in views change what ever you want.

```
 def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'current_page': int(self.request.query_params.get('page', 1)),
            'total': self.page.paginator.count,
            'per_page': self.page_size,
            'total_pages': round(self.page.paginator.count/self.page_size, 1),
            'data': data,
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#it is your pagination.py
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
from rest_framework.response import Response

class MyFavoritePagination(PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        nl = self.get_next_link()
        pl = self.get_previous_link()
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': nl[nl.find("/api") : ] if nl is not None else None,
                'previous': pl[pl.find("/api") : ] if pl is not None else None
            },
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'results': data
        })
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thx, im a newbie)

Answer (score 0):

We can subclass [PageNumberPagination](https://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.pagination/PageNumberPagination.html) and override `get_next_link()` and `get_previous_link()` methods to add domain different from one in `request` object:

```py
url = self.request.build_absolute_uri('https://front-end-domain.com')`
```

From `build_absolute_uri()` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri)